# swift static extension like c#

Tags: c#, swift

Hi is there any change to write static extension in Swift like is in C#? I mean in C# i can write same thing like this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int WordCount(this String str)
    {
        return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
var s = ""; var x = s.WordCount();
```

I know i can do same thing in swift, but it work only on class types. On static types I must write something like :

```
var str:String?
let s = String.IsNilOrEmpty(str)
```

for this extension:

```
extension String {
    static func isNilOrEmpty(str: String?) -> Bool{

        if str == nil {
            return true
        }

        if str!.isEmpty{
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

Is there change to call it like this:

```
let s = str.IsNilOrEmpty()
```

Thanks for help or kicking out to right way.

Comment: The problem is that `str` is an optional, so you'd need to define an extension to Optional.

Comment: You could just drop this into a playground to see if it works.

Comment: I did try it in Playground but with this result. If I used static extension, I can call this extension on optional type with this style `let some = String.isNilOrEmpty(someOptional)` or with static removed i can do `let some = someOptionalString.IsNilOrEmpty()`. But I looking for option call it in both situation same way (as is in my second example). If there is that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define functions with the same name, one static, one not static.

```
extension String {
    static func myfunc() -> String {
        return "static"
    }
    func myfunc() -> String {
        return "func"
    }
}

let s3 = ""
print(s3.myfunc()) // output = "func"
print(String.myfunc()) // output = "static"
```

In this case, if 'someOptionalString' is nil, then it will not call the function.

```
 let some = someOptionalString.IsNilOrEmpty()
```

Comment: Thanks, now I know that i can't call static extension on uninitialized type.